# How to turn off MVC form validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a data-first set-up so my models are generated by the entity framework from my database and there is no default [Required] annotations.  I have a simple table with three fields.  One ID and two VARCHAR / text based fields.

No matter what I try, I cannot get the CRUD forms to stop validation.  I disabled in the Web.config, I add [ValidateInput(false)] to the Create() method in the controller, but has no effect.  I set the @Html.ValidationSummary to false,

This is the basic view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

<fieldset>
    <legend>CallType</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CALLTYPE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("calltype", "", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CALLTYPE) 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Model (generated by Framework):

```
public partial class CALLTYPES2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CALLTYPE { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

Even if I insert just one character in each field, it still says: "The Value 'x' is invalid"
(I leave the validation messages on so I can see what is going on.)

What am I supposed to do?  And how would I validate these fields later on - can I just add [Required] to Model generated code?  What if I regenerate the Model from the database?

Does this have something to do with the model state in the controller?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CALLTYPES2 calltype)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CALLTYPES2.Add(calltype);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(calltype);
}
```

Not sure what I am missing and the tutorials I have read do not shed much light.  Thanks for your response and apologies for my ignorance.

**UPDATE**

Found my error - The object name "calltype" in the Method Create() is the same as the name/id of the form field "calltype".  I guess the binder tries to bind the string "calltype" to the object "calltype".  Renamed it to:

```
public ActionResult Create(CALLTYPES2 ctype)
```

Now it works in both the Edit and Create Windows.  "ctype" is not clashing with "calltype".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `ID` field in your form. You could include it as a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

Now the value of the ID property will be sent to the server when the form is submitted and the default model binder should not complain.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However adding the hidden field does not have any impact. Well there is no ID yet, so I put in a default but no luck.  I discovered the Model.IsValid is not true and the calltype object passed is null when it arrives at the controller.  Trying to work out why.  Seems like some binding issue?